# Can't start PostgreSQL on RHEL

Tags: postgresql

Can't start PostgreSQL-11, I see this message:
"""Job for postgresql-11.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-11.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."""
I think, that I have installed all necessary libs.
What should I add or change?

Firstly, I installed PostgreSQL with these commands:

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel- 
7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat11-11-2.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql11
yum install postgresql11-server
yum install postgresql11-contrib
yum install postgresql11-devel
yum install postgresql11-libs
```

Than I initialized the database and enabled automatic start:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-11
systemctl start postgresql-11
```

And after typing "systemctl status postgresql-11.service":

```
● postgresql-11.service - PostgreSQL 11 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-04-03 19:04:02 +05; 27min ago
     Docs: https://www.postgr...
  Process: 70442 ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postmaster -D ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 70436 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 70442 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server...
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.384 +05 [70...e
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.384 +05 [70....
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70...l
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70..."
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service: main process e...RE
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 11 databas...r.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-11.service entered fa...e.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

After "journalctl -xe":

```
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedes...
--
-- Unit postgresql-11.service has begun starting up.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.384 +05 [70442] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.384 +05 [70442] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70442] LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::1": Address family not supported by protocol
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70442] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70442] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp postmaster[70442]: 2019-04-03 19:04:02.387 +05 [70442] LOG:  database system is shut down
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 11 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-11.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesk...
--
-- Unit postgresql-11.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-11.service entered failed state.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service failed.
Apr 03 19:04:02 vm-grpapp polkitd[9026]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:70430:244359438 (system bus name :1.1876, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, lo
Apr 03 19:29:28 vm-grpapp sshd[69111]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 03 19:29:28 vm-grpapp systemd-logind[9025]: Removed session 764.
-- Subject: Session 764 has been terminated
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedes...
-- Documentation: http://www.freedes...
--
-- A session with the ID 764 has been terminated.
Apr 03 19:29:33 vm-grpapp sshd[69925]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 03 19:29:33 vm-grpapp systemd-logind[9025]: Removed session 767.
-- Subject: Session 767 has been terminated
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedes...
-- Documentation: http://www.freed...
--
-- A session with the ID 767 has been terminated.
Apr 03 19:31:12 vm-grpapp postfix/pickup[70566]: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol
```

This is my code:

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat11-11-2.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql11
yum install postgresql11-server
yum install postgresql11-contrib
yum install postgresql11-devel
yum install postgresql11-libs
```

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file. It will tell you what is wrong.